# C#: AppDomain Handling UnhandledException

Tags: c#, exception, appdomain, unhandled-exception

Im new in appdomain concept. Here's my questions regarding handling exception for appdomain recovery:

1. Is unloading the appdomain when unhandledException trigger is proper way of handling it?
2. Is it best practice that everytime I made a call to my appdomain i have to place it inside trycatch so whatever happens along the invocation I'm going to unload to avoid crashing my main domain?

I have my parent app domain then I created my child app domain named SandBox2.

```
        AppDomain sandbox2 = AppDomain.CreateDomain("SandBox2");
        UpdateLog(string.Format("Created AppDomain {0}", sandbox2.FriendlyName));
        try
        {
            sandbox2.ExecuteAssembly(x.ToString()); //along here null exception is triggered
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            AppDomain.Unload(sandbox2);
        }
```

Thank you